# Last-Modified が付いていない

Tags: http, curl

サイトの最終更新日を確認したいのですが、ソースの中身を見ても書いてありませんでした。
そこで以下のコマンドで、レスポンスヘッダを確認したのですが、Last-Modifiedの項目がありませんでした。（他のサイトでも試したのですが、同様に見当たらず）

```
curl --head https://www.youtube.com/
```

なぜなのか一通り調べ、サーバー側の設定が原因だと考えましたが、ほかの可能性があれば
詳しい方に教えていただきたく、質問しました。（試したサイトすべてにLast-Modified が入っていないので不思議です。）

Answer (score 3):

`Last-Modified` ヘッダーについては、[RFC7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.2) にて以下のように決められています（一部抜粋）。

> An origin server **SHOULD** send Last-Modified for any selected
> representation for which a last modification date can be reasonably
> and consistently determined,

ここで `MUST` ではなく `SHOULD` となっており、Web サーバーは必ずしも `Last-Modified` を送信する必要は無いことになっています。

例に挙げられている、YouTube のような [CGM](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Generated_Media) をはじめとする動的ページを生成する Web サービスでは、`Last-Modified` が実質レスポンス日時（`Date` ヘッダーの値）になりあまり意味を成さない為、付加しないケースは多くあります。